# I want to search users list from my firebase database according to the city entered by me

Tags: java, android

I have created an blood donation application and I want to search the list of donors according to my specifies blood group and city.

But can't able to do that.

Comment: show a screenshot of your database structure!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
myRef.orderByChild("BloodGroup")
            .equalTo("Type O")
            .orderByChild("city")
            .equalTo("NY");
```